# Express is not working on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, express

I have installed nodejs,express on ubuntu but when i type "express test" command on terminal on ubuntu, its not creating the folders etc (package.json,app.js, view folder ect).It simply prompts in the next line.
Please help

Comment: Logged by root? The user has permission to create folder in that path? Provide more details, as version express, node, ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate the scaffolding for a new express app you can use the `express-generator`.

First you need to install the needed module **globaly**.

`sudo npm install express-generator -g`

Then you can use this command to generate your scaffolding.

`express <my_app>`

More info here http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html

Comment: The command sudo npm install express-generator -g is executed successfully but also after running express myapp gives no floders ,jus prompts $ in next line